# What are Datastore Entity Fetch Ops?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I have a problem in my GAE app. I have too many Datastore Entity Fetch Ops but I don't know where they come from...

Does anybody know what makes Datastore Entity Fetch Ops???

Comment: Could you provide snippets of your code and some more information so as to be able to help you?

Answer (score 3):

You can use appstats to find oiut where they come from: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/appstats

Comment: Ok, my problem is probably the following. I have an application sending CGM messages. The device info are in the DB. But to avoid to many read operations, I also put the devices info in memcache. However, 2000 CGM registrations keys in a String in memecache is maybe too much. My memcache is erased and I have to reload it. Everytime 2000 read operations... Do you have another idea?

Comment: Have you considered looking at/converting to  NDB? It can manage some aspects of caching for you also, https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/cache

Comment: Hm... the problem is actually something else. I used the datastore viewer to list the 1000 first entries. And it looks like the viewer counts 20+40+60+80+...+1000. That makes about 25'000 operations!:(

Answer (score 0):

Datastore query or fetch calls.